# subsetting in nested list r

Tags: r, list, nested, subset

I have the following list:

```
mylist<-list(c("25","0"),c("50","1"),c("100","2"))
```

And I want to extract at once the first element of each element on the list. That is

```
c(mylist[[1]][1],mylist[[2]][1],mylist[[3]][1])
```

I tried the following but without sucess:

```
mylist[[]][1]; mylist[[.]][1]; mylist[1:3][1]
```

I appreciate any suggestions to do this efficiently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another `lapply` solution:

```
lapply(mylist,"[", 1)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "25"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "50"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "100"
> ```

With `purrr` we could also do:

```
purrr::map(mylist, ~ .x[1])
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "25"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "50"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "100"
> ```

However, `lapply` should be faster.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them as an atomic vector, you can use:

```
mylist <- list(c("25","0"),c("50","1"),c("100","2"))

sapply(mylist, function(v) v[1])
## [1] "25"  "50"  "100"
```

Or to get them as a list:

```
lapply(mylist, function(v) v[1])
## [[1]]
## [1] "25"
## [[2]]
## [1] "50"
## [[3]]
## [1] "100"
```

Comment: and for a list, `lapply` instead of `sapply`